# Order by content in Drupal 7 module

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-7

I have 3 variable in my custom module:

```
  $day = date('d',strtotime($nd->field_edate['und'][0]['value'],time()));

  $dayname = date('w',strtotime($nd->field_edate['und'][0]['value'],time()));

  $hours = date('H:i',strtotime($nd->field_edate['und'][0]['value'],time()));
```

And my content order by DESC.

```
$rs = $data->orderBy("n.created","desc")->execute();
```

But I want, it uses order by `$day`, `$dayname` or `$hours`.

When I tried to like this:

```
$rs = $data->orderBy("n.created","'$hours.'")->execute();
```

My pseudo code I want:

```
$rs = $data->orderBy("order by near date today")->execute();
```

It's not working.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only order by database fields, not arbitrary PHP variables.

If you want to order by the field edate first you will need to join to that table.

For this example I am assuming that edate is a field attached to a node of type article.

```
$data->join('field_data_field_edate', 'e', "e.entity_id = n.nid AND e.bundle = 'article'");
```

Now you can use:

```
$data->orderBy("e.field_edate_value", "ASC");
```

This will order by whatever value is in the edate field. If that is a timestamp, and you want to order by the dayname then you could use:

```
$data->addExpression("DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(e.field_edate_value))", 'day_name');
```

And then you can order by your expression:

```
$data->orderBy("day_name", "ASC");
```